# Netcode for Gameobject: Serverside Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, multiplayer

I am currently making my first experience with the Netcode for Gameobject package from unity.

I would like to implement a server authorized movement of players. Here I encounter various problems and hope you can help me at this point or give me some food for thought.

So I have a playerprefab which has the network transform component in it. In this I have selected that only the X and Y coordinates should be synchronized.

The first try looked like this

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class PlayerNetwork : NetworkBehaviour
{
    Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    float speed = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;

        moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) moveDir.y = -1f;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) moveDir.y = +1f;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) moveDir.x = -1f;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) moveDir.x = +1f;


        transform.position =  moveDir* speed * Time.deltaTime;
      
    }
}
```

in this attempt, the host can move itself, but the client cannot.

I understood that the client initiates the movement locally, but the Network Transform component synchronizes the server's movement data over it again.

So I assumed I had to tell the server the new position so it would sync the new position to the client.

Thus my next attempt:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class PlayerNetwork : NetworkBehaviour
{
    Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    float speed = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;

        moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) moveDir.y = -1f;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) moveDir.y = +1f;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) moveDir.x = -1f;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) moveDir.x = +1f;


        Vector3 pos =  moveDir* speed * Time.deltaTime;
      
        moveServerRPC(pos);
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    void moveServerRPC(Vector3 pos)
    {
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Now the client can move, but it feels very "hakelig".

It got better after I disabled interpolating on the Network Transform.

Additionally I rewrote the ServerRPC function as follows:

```cs
 [ServerRpc]
    void moveServerRPC(Vector3 pos)
    {
        transform.Translate(pos);
    }
```

now the movements look smoother but the movement on the client still feels staggered and a bit spongy. Of course, this would be unthinkable for an FPS shooter or similar. But even if it doesn't matter in terms of gameplay, it just doesn't feel good to use.

In the respective readings, it is always recommended to control the movement via a Client Network Transform component, but at the same time it is not recommended to do so in competitive games. Unfortunately, I can't find any examples of this.

How would one proceed here? How far off is my idea and what would have to be changed to get a fluid but server controlled movement?

Comment: In general you never want to send networked messages each and every frame! A) they will arrive delayed at the remote clients B) they might not be received in their original send intervals so it could be jumping again C) that's a lot of networking traffic and fully depends on frame rates! => Usually you send only some updates (e.g. every 0.2 seconds) and then rather interpolate on the receiver side. You should then also not transmit Translation but the actual target position

Comment: Now I don't know Netcode in detail but to my understanding if you are the owner of the NetworkTransform you should be only sending, all others only receiving (except the server who receives and forwards to all others except you) ...

Comment: In your first code I guess you are missing a `+` as in `transform.position   +=    moveDir* speed * Time.deltaTime;` right?

Comment: The owner is the player who owns that object. So the code isn’t executed by other player nor the server. 
The network transform component receives continuously the known position of the server of this object.